# Initiation of table and dbms_output.put_line

Tags: plsql

**TASK**:
define PL/SQL table, which elements is records. The Record structure should be the same like in Subjects talbe. Initiate 5 elements of new table, using consequent and increment index, starting from 1. Input values into every record. Print (output) inputted data, describing it in readable way.

**Subjects table structure is**:

Id NUMBER(3), //primary key

Subj_name VARCHAR2(40),

Description VARCHAR2(200)

**This is my attempt**:

```
SET serveroutput on;
CREATE TABLE Subject
(
  IdSubj NUMBER(3),
  SubjName VARCHAR2(40),
  Descr VARCHAR2(500)
);
BEGIN
For i IN 1..5 LOOP
INSERT INTO Subject(IdSubj, SubjName, Descr)
VALUES(i, 'Subject number: ' || TO_CHAR(i), 'Description of subject ');
dbms_output.put_line('Id subj: ' || i || ', Subject:' || ', Descr: ');
END LOOP;
END;
```

**Questions**:

1) Did I initiate SubjName record in correct way ('Subject number: ' || TO_CHAR(i))?

2) How to output 2nd and 3rd values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "output 2nd and 3rd values" you mean the values you inserted into the SUBJNAME and DESCR columns you could use the RETURNING clause to save the inserted values and then output the values from the variables, as in:

```
DECLARE
  strSubjname  SUBJECT.SUBJNAME%TYPE;
  strDescr     SUBJECT.DESCR%TYPE;
BEGIN
  For i IN 1..5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO SUBJECT(IdSubj, SubjName, Descr)
      VALUES(i, 'Subject number: ' || TO_CHAR(i), 'Description of subject ')
      RETURNING SUBJNAME, DESCR INTO strSubjname, strDescr;

    dbms_output.put_line('Id subj: ' || i ||
                         ', Subject:' || strSubjname ||
                         ', Descr: ' || strDescr);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.